# Can't use MAX in an Update Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a bit of SQL which looks like this.

```
UPDATE TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT
SET PRINCIPAL = CASE 
                   WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.D.7' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL 
                   WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.A.1' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL
                   WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.8' THEN TPOS.PRINAMT 
                END, 
    INTEREST = CASE 
                  WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.O.19' THEN TPOS.QTY * SECS.INTPAYAMT_8 
                  WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.6' THEN (TPOS.QTY * SELECT(MAX(SECS.INTPAYAMT_8))) 
               END,
    INTPAYAMTQTY = CASE 
                      WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.W.16' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL + (TPOS.QTY*SECS.INTPAYAMT_8) 
                   END, 
    REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = CASE 
                           WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.D.7' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL 
                           WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.A.1' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL
                           WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.8' THEN TPOS.PRINAMT
                           WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.O.19' THEN TPOS.QTY * SECS.INTPAYAMT_8
                           WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.6' THEN (TPOS.QTY * SELECT(MAX(SECS.INTPAYAMT_8)))
                           WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.W.16' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL + (TPOS.QTY*SECS.INTPAYAMT_8)
                        END
FROM TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_HIST AS RawData 
INNER JOIN TBL_FR2052A_SECS_HIST AS SECS 
INNER JOIN TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT AS TPOS ON SECS.SECID = TPOS.SECID 
                                               AND SECS.ASOFDATE = TPOS.ASOFDATE 
      ON RawData.SourceID_Revised = TPOS.SourceID_Revised 
      AND RawData.AsofDate = TPOS.ASOFDATE
```

Now, I am trying to get the MAX of `SECS.INTPAYAMT_8`

I thought it would be something like this:

```
WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.6' THEN (TPOS.QTY * MAX(SECS.INTPAYAMT_8)) END,
```

Of course, that doesn't work. I looked online and it says you have to use a subquery. I tried a few ideas, but nothing worked so far.

Any experts here know how to do this kind of thing? TIA.

Comment: Before inner join SECS, calc out MAX(SECS.INTPAYAMT_8) first, then join with RawData.

Comment: Hummm, I tried and it didn't work.  Can you post an example?

Comment: Can you do a subquery? 
E.g.
WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.6' THEN (TPOS.QTY * (SELECT MAX(INTPAYAMT_8) FROM TABLE) END,

Comment: You do this kind of thing with a subquery. But your code does not have a valid subquery. A subquery need to have a FROM clause, not just a column in the outer query.

Comment: @tonyd, I tried the exact same thing before you posted that and it didn't work.  It says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before join SECS, calculate MAX(SECS.INTPAYAMT_8) first.

So the codes will be like below (You need to optimize the codes based on your schema):

```
UPDATE       TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT
SET          PRINCIPAL = CASE WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.D.7' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL 
                WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.A.1' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL
                WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.8' THEN TPOS.PRINAMT END, 
             INTEREST = CASE WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.O.19' THEN TPOS.QTY * SECS.INTPAYAMT_8 
                WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.6' THEN (TPOS.QTY * MAX_INTPAYAMT_8) END,
             INTPAYAMTQTY = CASE WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.W.16' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL + (TPOS.QTY*SECS.INTPAYAMT_8) END,   
             REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = CASE WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.D.7' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL 
                WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.A.1' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL
                WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.8' THEN TPOS.PRINAMT
                WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.O.19' THEN TPOS.QTY * SECS.INTPAYAMT_8
                WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.6' THEN (TPOS.QTY * MAX_INTPAYAMT_8)
                WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.W.16' THEN TPOS.MKTVAL + (TPOS.QTY*SECS.INTPAYAMT_8)END
FROM         TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_HIST AS RawData INNER JOIN
             (
             select *, 
             -- Calculate out MAX_INTPAYAMT_8
             max(INTPAYAMT_8) over (partition by ID) MAX_INTPAYAMT_8  --I do not know your schema, so use partiion by ID
                 from TBL_FR2052A_SECS_HIST
             )
 AS SECS INNER JOIN TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT AS TPOS ON SECS.SECID = TPOS.SECID AND 
             SECS.ASOFDATE = TPOS.ASOFDATE ON RawData.SourceID_Revised = TPOS.SourceID_Revised AND 
             RawData.AsofDate = TPOS.ASOFDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, get the max of INTPAYAMT_8 in a seperate subquery then join it to your main query.

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.D.7'
                THEN TPOS.MKTVAL
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.A.1'
                THEN TPOS.MKTVAL
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.8'
                THEN TPOS.PRINAMT
            END PRINCIPAL_, CASE 
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.O.19'
                THEN TPOS.QTY * SECS.INTPAYAMT_8
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.6'
                THEN (TPOS.QTY * T.INTPAYAMT_8)
            END INTEREST_, CASE 
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.W.16'
                THEN TPOS.MKTVAL + (TPOS.QTY * SECS.INTPAYAMT_8)
            END INTPAYAMTQTY_, CASE 
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.D.7'
                THEN TPOS.MKTVAL
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.A.1'
                THEN TPOS.MKTVAL
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.8'
                THEN TPOS.PRINAMT
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.O.19'
                THEN TPOS.QTY * SECS.INTPAYAMT_8
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'I.O.6'
                THEN (TPOS.QTY * T.INTPAYAMT_8)
            WHEN TPOS.PID = 'O.W.16'
                THEN (TPOS.MKTVAL + (TPOS.QTY * SECS.INTPAYAMT_8))
            END REPORTABLE_AMOUNT_, PRINCIPAL, INTEREST, INTPAYAMTQTY, REPORTABLE_AMOUNT
    FROM TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_HIST AS RawData
    INNER JOIN TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT AS TPOS ON (
            RawData.SourceID_Revised = TPOS.SourceID_Revised
            AND RawData.AsofDate = TPOS.ASOFDATE
            )
    INNER JOIN TBL_FR2052A_SECS_HIST AS SECS ON (
            SECS.SECID = TPOS.SECID
            AND SECS.ASOFDATE = TPOS.ASOFDATE
            )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT RawData.SourceID_Revised, TPOS.ASOFDATE, MAX(SECS.INTPAYAMT_8) INTPAYAMT_8
        FROM TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_HIST AS RawData
        INNER JOIN TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT AS TPOS ON (
                RawData.SourceID_Revised = TPOS.SourceID_Revised
                AND RawData.AsofDate = TPOS.ASOFDATE
                )
        INNER JOIN TBL_FR2052A_SECS_HIST AS SECS ON (
                SECS.SECID = TPOS.SECID
                AND SECS.ASOFDATE = TPOS.ASOFDATE
                )
        GROUP BY RawData.SourceID_Revised, TPOS.ASOFDATE
        ) T ON RawData.SourceID_Revised = T.SourceID_Revised
        AND RawData.AsofDate = T.ASOFDATE
    )
UPDATE CTE
SET PRINCIPAL = PRINCIPAL_, INTEREST = INTEREST_, INTPAYAMTQTY = INTPAYAMTQTY_, REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = REPORTABLE_AMOUNT_
```